# Can't bind ListView to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

This my ViewModel:

```
namespace DietAndFitness.ViewModels
{
public class FoodItemsViewModel 
{
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public static ObservableCollection<GlobalFoodItem> FoodItems { get; set; }

    public FoodItemsViewModel(SQLiteAsyncConnection _database)
    {
        database = _database;        
    }

    public async void LoadList()
    {
         FoodItems = new ObservableCollection<GlobalFoodItem>(await database.Table<GlobalFoodItem>().ToListAsync());
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        FoodItems.Add(new GlobalFoodItem("Item"));
    }
}
}
```

I want to bind an instance of this VM to the list in my View but I just can't get it to work properly. The only thing I've managed to get to work is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DietAndFitness.ViewModels"
         x:Class="DietAndFitness.Views.FoodDatabasePage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FoodItems}" RowHeight="120">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView Padding="5">
                            <Frame OutlineColor="Accent" Padding="10">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Calories}" FontSize="22" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Text="Carbohydrates" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label Text="Proteins" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label Text="Fats" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding Carbohydrates}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Proteins}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Fats}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="AddFoodItemButton" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Add" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="AddFoodItemButton_Clicked" />
            <Button x:Name="EditFoodItemButton" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Edit" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button x:Name="DeleteFoodItemButton" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Delete" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But this has problems too:

1. If I create the VM in the page constructor the list won't load unless I refresh the page
2. If I create the VM inside App.cs the list will load on the first try but then I can't seem to access the instance of the VM

How do I bind my ListView to this VM? And is it possible to do so without making my ObservableCollection static? 
I'm using a Master-Detail page in my app if it makes any difference (this is one of the detail pages).

Edit: Here is what I did in the constructor. SQLiteConnection.Database is just a static class that contains the connection to the database.

```
    public FoodDatabasePage ()
    {
        FoodDatabase = new FoodItemsViewModel(SQLiteConnection.Database);
        FoodDatabase.LoadList();
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the C# constructor for DietAndFitness.Views.FoodDatabasePage

Comment: @DavidS I added the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that you have there.

When binding a ViewModel usually it's against the whole `Page` making the ViewModel its `BindingContext` specially in cases like yours when you have methods that want to access later.

So to do this you will need a few changes.

**Your Page XAML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DietAndFitness.ViewModels"
        x:Class="DietAndFitness.Views.FoodDatabasePage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FoodItems}" 
                RowHeight="120">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Accent" Padding="15">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                        Grid.Row="0" 
                                        Grid.Column="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Check that I changed the `ListView` `ItemSource` for the name of the collection in your `FoodItemsViewModel`.

Also, part of your XAML disappeared so I could not complete it.

**Your Code Behind class:** (FoodDatabasePage.xaml.cs)

```
public FoodItemsViewModel FoodDatabase {get; set;}

public FoodDatabasePage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    FoodDatabase = new FoodItemsViewModel(SQLiteConnection.Database);
    BindingContext = FoodDatabase;
}

public override void OnAppearing()
{
    FoodDatabase.LoadList();    
}
```

Here is where the "magic" happens. We are creating and storing the object of our `FoodItemsViewModel` so you can access it later as you need and then we are setting this object recently created as the `BindingContext` of the page (as explained above). Setting the ViewModel as the BindingContext of `Page` the latter will be able to access any public property of the `FoodItemsViewModel`.

Also, you will notice the `LoadList()` method was removed from the constructor, this is because there shouldn't be any heavy transaction (actually we should avoid any transactions) in the `Page` constructor. We moved it instead to the `OnAppearing` callback method that is executed by the `Page` when this is about to be displayed.

Note: This method is called every time the Page is presented on the screen so if you navigate away and come back it will be called again.

**Your ViewModel:**

```
namespace DietAndFitness.ViewModels
{
    public class FoodItemsViewModel 
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        //You don't need it static
        public ObservableCollection<GlobalFoodItem> FoodItems { get; set; }

        public FoodItemsViewModel(SQLiteAsyncConnection _database)
        {
            database = _database;        
        }

        public async void LoadList()
        {
            // separated it only for readability.
            var items = await database.Table<GlobalFoodItem>().ToListAsync();
            FoodItems = new ObservableCollection<GlobalFoodItem>(items);
        }

        public void Add()
        {
            FoodItems.Add(new GlobalFoodItem("Item"));
        }
    }
}
```

This remains almost the same. The only change was removing the `static` qualifier to the `FoodItems` property since it does not need it anymore.

The above is just the basic of Mvvm and DataBinding. There're a few other things that you will need to take into consideration like `INotifiedPropertyChanged`, `Command`s and other important things.

You can find more information regarding this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Hope this helps.-

PS: I couldn't check all of your code for any error.

Comment: I made the changes and I updated the post with the full FoodDatabasePage.xaml but it's still not working. The page is blank with only the buttons.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to solve it. Apparently INotifiyProperty MUST be implemented for the ListView binding to work and populate the list. Somehow I expected the ListView to be populated at least a first time without it and just not update. Thank you for the answer, it has been insightful.